# Google Maps not showing details

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I have an android app that is supposed to track an order that is in a certain truck at a given time .Am using the google maps android api for this , my problem is that my map is not detailed enough to show without much effort where the truck is? Could this be an  issue with the plan am using ,because am using the standard plan or what might be the issue. i know its a simple question but am not so sure what is happening,thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to create api key for goolgle map from  and add into manifest file .
Please create your google map proejct and create api key with package.
https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: what is the simple method you are using?

Comment: @ChayanChowdhury Am actually rendering the map , the issue is that  the map is not detailed like lets say  roads are not visible

Comment: @RushiAyyappa  which methods ??

Comment: i refer to you standard plan of updating map .

Comment: @RushiAyyappa Am using a standard plan as of now ??

Comment: Yes,Standard plan..can you elaborate your standard plan here?

Comment: @RushiAyyappa google Api has two plans the standard plan which is free and premium which is paid for ......

Comment: oh you were telling about the Pricing .okay.you do not need a premium plan. standard plan is good enough

Comment: and if you want a detailed report about the truck locaiton try from coding side getting accurate coordinates and showing them on the map.

Comment: Is the map somehow less detailed than when viewing Google Maps in a browser on a computer? If they look the same, then that's just the state of Google Maps in that region.

Comment: @RushiAyyappa Yea i thought maybe it was an issue with the plan i was using ,thanks anyway i will observe the truck in another location and see if the problem is the location

Answer (score 2):

So if i get it right, your map is already working, but its not detailed enough? You can switch your View to Satellite View like this:

```
 mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

And if you increase the zoom, you get a more detailed View, for Example:

```
// Move the camera instantly to yout specific location with a zoom of 17.

 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 17));
```

Comment: This is what i have but its not detailed like for instance how uber is or when you using the maps app on your phone .

Comment: Is it a rural area? Maybe its because of your area and there are no detailed data available at the Moment?